# Check if PH or AFT model should be fit

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

It is unclear to me when it is appropriate to fit an accelerated failure time (AFT) model rather than a proportional hazard (PH) model.

I've tried googling and it appears as though PH models are much more popular than AFT models and I haven't been able to find much material speaking regarding the use of one model type over the other.

I've attached an image of a section from *Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data* that gives some guidelines for graphical methods but they don't seem feasible with a large number of covariates.

Would anyone be able to provide some intuition into when each model type is appropriate?

[image]